# Hacking paywalls on newsites?

Tags: halacha, internet, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, contemporary-halacha

Many news websites (NY Times, Wall Street Journal, Washington Post etc.) make use of paywalls which pop up after the visitor starts reading the article requiring the visitor to pay in order to continue reading the article. Is it assur for one to set up their browser in a way so that paywalls don't pop up (not an incognito window)?

Answer (score -1):

It is clearly documented in Jewish Law that one may not **cheat** in money matters, that one may not **steal** - even from non-Jews, and that one may not **deceive** others.

Review these important laws in Kitzur Shlchan Aruch in Siman [63](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.63?lang=bihttps://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.63?lang=bi) and [64](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.64?lang=bi).

It would seem that bypassing paywalls falls into at least one of these categories.

Comment: I don't see how this is cheating in money matters. Maybe because that's a vague term. Could you please clarify what you mean. I believe the whole question is asking if this is stealing, and you're simply writing "it would seem so". Why? And deceiving others would seem irrelevant here.

Comment: The news outlets make their content and put in work, which is to be paid for. Therefore it is indeed money matters. You steal the content of their work, by not paying.

Comment: @BenTizyon By that logic you steal by reading, e.g. Stack Exchange without paying, because they also put in work to make content. The question is whether news sites putting up a paywall makes it forbidden, which apparently has yet to be demonstrated.

Comment: @robev - I'm unclear what you are asking: I put up a paywall so that you pay me to read my content. You bypass it - why is that honest? OTOH StackExchange provides us with a free platform - why would that be dishonest to use, as long as I keep to the T&C?

Comment: @DonCorleone - if I decide that to walk through my square mile of desert you have to pay me, and you get around that, aren't you stealing? I didn't do anything more than put up a sign and tie a pushka to a pole.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Intellectual property is not accepted as a valid halachic argument by  all rabbis

Comment: @DonCorleone - why is this "intellectual property"? I can understand (at some level) why some would think that I can "re-use" ideas or music once I've mentally (or otherwise) recorded them. But here I put up a (virtual) wall & lock - and you are breaking through it. (And if you don't believe in virtual locks, then why not become rich with online-banking theft?)

Comment: The paywall is there to restrict access to copyrighted works

Comment: @DonCorleone - I know; that's what we're discussing. But who cares if it's protecting hot air or my bank account. You're "breaking in". Would you approve of me picking the lock on your garden gate to merely walk on the paved path to smell your delicious roses? That's at least as nebulous as IP, if not less.